# Calculate expiration date based on server data

Tags: c#, xamarin

This code yet is not really optimize and I know that . But for now this is all I have.

What this code does is that it computes the expiration date of an account.

By the way I need to do the swapping workaround because the date that the server gives to me are inverted so I need to do a lil workaround about that.

```cs
    /// <summary>
    /// Add revalidation text and how many days the agents account will expire
    /// </summary>
    public async void RevalidateAccount()
    {
        //Get Stored Persistent Data of Date
        string _expDateFromPersistent = await SecureStorage.GetAsync("ExpirationDate");

        //Check if empty or not
        //because if it is empty we need to hide the validation text first
        //then show it after relogging in
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(_expDateFromPersistent))
        {
            IsVisibleValidationText = true;
            //Convert string date to DateTime
            DateTime expDate = Convert.ToDateTime(_expDateFromPersistent);
            DateTime todayDate = DateTime.Now;
            //Change Format
            string _dateToday = todayDate.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

            //Swap workaround
            string day = expDate.Day.ToString();
            string month = expDate.Month.ToString();
            string year = expDate.Year.ToString();
            string _expirationDate = year + "/" + day + "/" + month; 
            //Calculation
            TimeSpan expirationDate = DateTime.Parse(_expirationDate) - DateTime.Parse(_dateToday);
            //Business Rule: 7 days prior to 30 days show the revalidation text
            if (expirationDate.Days <= 7)
            {
                if (IsVisibleValidationText)
                {
                    //Formatted Text for validation text
                    Revalidate = new FormattedString();
                    Revalidate.Spans.Add(new Span { Text = "You have ", ForegroundColor = Color.FromHex(_textColor), FontSize = 15 });
                    Revalidate.Spans.Add(new Span { Text = $"{expirationDate.Days} days", ForegroundColor = Color.FromHex(_textColor), FontSize = 15, FontAttributes = FontAttributes.Bold });
                    Revalidate.Spans.Add(new Span { Text = " left before you need \n to re-validate your login credentials.", ForegroundColor = Color.FromHex(_textColor), FontSize = 15 });
                    await _pageDialogService.DisplayAlertAsync("NOTICE", "You have " + expirationDate.Days + " days left before you need to re-validate your login credentials.", "OK");
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            IsVisibleValidationText = false;
        }
    }
```

What my code does is that it gets the data(Expiration Date) from the server then I just need to differ the `DateTime.Now` and the date(expiration date) from the server to have an expiration date.

Comment: ok, I think the question is fixed now ;-)

Answer (score 3):

General naming guidelines suggest that an async method should end its name with "Async", so the method name should be `RevalidateAccountAsync`.

Some would argue that a underscore prefix should never be used for naming of any variables.  For those that do allow underscore prefixes, it should only be for class-level variables and never used for variables local to a given method.

When comparing or manipulating 2 `DateTime` objects, the proper way to do that is to be sure that both have the same `Kind`.  Oddly enough, your code does that since you jump through so many hoops to create new `DateTime` objects with `Kind` of `Unspecified`.

`expirationDate` is a misleading name since it is not a date.  It is a `TimeSpan`.

After checking `expirationDate.Days <= 7`, there is no need to check `IsVisibleValidateText` since it will always be true at that point.

Your code looks to be twice as long as it needs to be because of all the manipulation of `DateTime` and `string`.  For example, to get today's date should only be 1 line:

`DateTime todayDate = DateTime.Today; \\Kind is Local`

`expDate` could use `DateTime.Parse` or `Convert.ToDateTime`.  However, you should also set it's Kind because as it is it will be `Unspecified` unless the string contains any time zone offset.  Example setting it to Local:

`DateTime expDate = DateTime.SpecifyKind(Convert.ToDateTime(_expDateFromPersistent), DateTimeKind.Local);`

The alternative would be to keep `expDate` as `Unspecified` but then make `todayDate` also `Unspecified`.

`DateTime todayDate = DateTime.SpecifyKind(DateTime.Today, DateTimeKind.Unspecified);`

Since it looks like you are interested in dates starting a midnight, skip the slower string manipulation and instead use the `DateTime.Date` property.  See help at [this link](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.date?view=netframework-4.8).  Example:

`TimeSpan expirationDate = expDate.Date - todayDate;`

Which gets rid of all the slower and unneeded string variables, both dates above have the same `Kind`, and both are set to midnight.